# Microcontroller works on breadboard, but not on PCB (which is proven to be correct)

Tags: microcontroller, led, pcb, breadboard, attiny

**Summary**: I have two circuits: One on breaboard and one on PCB. I have two Microcontrollers: A commercial one (pre programmed) and a personal one (with whom I try to recreate the commercial one). The commercial uC works in both circuits and my recreated one works only in the breadboard. I dont understand how one can work on both and the other doesn't.

## Context

**Disclaimer**: All resources like schematics, images, code, etc. can be found below. I try to be as thorough as possible with this question.

I bought a simple electrice dice circuit, which will "roll" a dice with a press of a button. This uses LEDs and a uC to do and came pre programmed (see below for an image). When the button is pressed, the LEDs will flicker and when released, the rolled number will stay for 3 seconds, until the LEDs turn off. This is super simple, consisting only out of LEDs, Resistors, Batteries, a button, and an uC which is ATTiny13 by Atmel.

My goal is to recreate the programming of the uC myself and eventually build similar circuits myself (start small, right?).

Now, I have the schematics of the commercial one (see first image below) and rebuilt it all on my breadboard (see 2nd image below). I validated this circuit by taking the ATTiny13 from the commercial version (it is removable due to a socket) and put it in my self made circuit. Everythings works perfectly.

Then I started to program my first own ATTiny13. I did some simple LED blinking tests and then tried a dice script from a website to test it out (see code below). All of this works perfectly fine on my breadboard. Also rolling the dice will work great.

The moment, I put this into the commercial PCB (with the same schematics), nothing works. Neither the blinking script or the dice script will result in any LED blinking. Pressing the button will not change anything.

Many things come to my mind which could be an issue, but it comes down to one point: "When the PCB and the circuit on the breadboard are indeed the same schematic and are similar, a uC which works on one, shall work on the other." This is true for the commercial one, but not for mine. I am really puzzled by this and my limited electronics knowledge is now catching up on me. Maybe PCBs behave differently after all? I checked thoroughly both circuits and they seem to be exactly like the schematics.

I am very happy for any help or hint in the right direction. Currently I dont even know for what to look out for. I think I might oversee something fundamental here.

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond, much appreciated!

## Resources

### General Info

R1       -   5.6k Ohm
R2       -   10k  Ohm
R3 R4 R6 -   15   Ohm
R5       -   120  Ohm

Vcc are three 1.5V batteries (4.5V)

Microcontroller: ATTiny13
[Datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A300/attiny_13v-10xx.pdf)

For programming, I use the Arduino IDE and an Arduino Nano as ISP (I followed [this guide](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/taunoerik/programming-attiny13-with-arduino-uno-07beba)). I program the ATTiny with the following settings (although I know hardly anything about the meaning of those):

**BOD:** 4.3V
**EEPROM:** EEPROM retained
**Clock:** 1.2 MHz, internal osc.
**Timing:** Micros disabled

### Circuit Schematic

[image: Circuit Schematic]

### Breadboard Circuit

[image: Breadboard Circuit]

### PCB Circuit

[image: PCB Circuit]

### Code

```
/* 
 *  The LEDs are arranged like this
 *  
 *  LED3      LED6
 *  LED2 LED7 LED5
 *  LED1      LED4
 *  
 *  
 *  
 *  AtTiny13 Pins
 *  ---------------------
 *          1_o___8 5V
 *  LED34   2_____7 LED25
 *  LED7    3_____6 LED16
 *  GND     4_____5 BTN
 *  -----------------------
 *  
 *  
 */

// The pins will be addressed using their PB Number (see above)
int pinLed16 = 1;
int pinLed25 = 2;
int pinLed34 = 3;
int pinLed7 = 4;
int pinButton = 0;
int buttonState;
long ran;
int time = 2000;

void setup ()
{
  pinMode (pinLed16, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (pinLed25, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (pinLed34, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (pinLed7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (pinButton, INPUT);
  // This resulted in an error, so it is commented out for now.
  //randomSeed(analogRead(A3));
}

void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(pinButton);
  if (buttonState == HIGH){
    ran = random(1, 7);
    if (ran == 1){
      digitalWrite (pinLed7, HIGH);
      delay (time);
    }
    if (ran == 2){
      digitalWrite (pinLed16, HIGH);
      delay (time);
    }
    if (ran == 3){
      digitalWrite (pinLed34, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed7, HIGH);
      delay (time);
    }
    if (ran == 4){
      digitalWrite (pinLed16, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed34, HIGH);
      delay (time);
    }
    if (ran == 5){
      digitalWrite (pinLed16, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed34, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed7, HIGH);
      delay (time);
   }
   if (ran == 6){
      digitalWrite (pinLed16, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed25, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (pinLed34, HIGH);
      delay (time);
   }
  }
  digitalWrite (pinLed16, LOW);
  digitalWrite (pinLed25, LOW);
  digitalWrite (pinLed34, LOW);
  digitalWrite (pinLed7, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Have you measured with a multimeter what is the actual supply voltage on breadboard batteries versus whatever is powering the commercial board?

Comment: They obviously skipped it, but I would try adding a 100 nF bypass capacitor from Vcc to GND as close to the µC as possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The supply voltage is 4.18 on the pcb circuit and 4.57 on the breadboard circuit.

Comment: @Arsenal, can you point me to a good resource regarding bypass capacitors? I dont understand that concept yet and need to learn it.

Comment: [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440430/placing-bypass-capacitors-after-vcc-reaches-the-ic) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392460/should-i-add-bypass-capacitor-for-every-ic-and-microcontroller) might get you started - note the links there as well.

Comment: @DesperateCookie //randomSeed(analogRead(A3));  this should be:   randomSeed(analogRead(3));  as used on ATtiny85 ?

Comment: Note that "breadbord" are very "capacitive". So the different behavior ?

Comment: Never put a microcontroller on a board without a bypass capacitor connected to it's power pin. Even if you think it's not needed, start with it connected and later if you need to save the extra 2 cents try removing it once everything is working.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is the 4.3V BOD (brown-out detector) level combined with old batteries.

The BOD level of 4.3V does not make sense as microcontroller will be in reset if batteries currently only provide 4.18V.

Use a lower BOD level.

2.7V BOD level should be fine for starters. Full batteries might provide 1.6V per cell (4.8V) and are considered empty at around 0.9V per cell (2.7V).

Comment: That's a good hint. And if it should also run on 3x NiMH it must be lower as well.

Comment: It seems that on "arduino", for ATTINY85, this is set to 2.7V? For ATTINY13 set at 4.3V, confirmed. Can be changed very easily.

Comment: I could give you a hug right now! I was already mentally prepared for a long and hard solution, but this was actually the only thing that it needed. Works wonderfully now! Thanks you so much for taking the time and give this reply!

Comment: It is always good to confirm the core for these discussions.  I assume it was MCUDude's MicroCore?  Has no effect unless you actually burn the fuses so the factory defaults may also be important.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What is the matter with the cores? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you’ve added the missing bypass capacitor, try this:

Unplug the MCU and measure the voltages on the socket relative to 4- confirm 8 and 1 are 5V. Confirm that 5 is 0V and becomes 5V when the switch is pressed.

Then jumper a 150 ohm resistor from 8 to each of 3, 2, 7 and 6 and confirm for each that the expected LEDs light.

If everything checks out, move the chip from the breadboard to the PCB- they appear to be different chips.

Comment: Hello, although the other one was the solution, this is valuable advice for debugging. Thanks, I will keep it in mind :)