# Decoupling cap value?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

We are a design using 3 decoupling capacitors the value are 47 uF 16 V X5R, but we are having trouble with the supplier.

I have an idea to replace them with 1 capacitor 100 uF, 1 10 uF and 0.1 uF.
This value is common to find them.
Anyone has a better value to be replaced this 3 decoupling caps?

Thanks

Comment: Replace it with the same value (or nearby value) and or different dielectric, max voltage rating. Try to use the same 3 caps, or something like this will occur https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHSyV.png you can see the 3 different caps ( the solid line with 3 anti resonance peaks) is mostly worse than the dotted (3 same value caps line). If no-one answers this by tonight I will write better answer. For now: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320363/antiresonance-of-multiple-parallel-decoupling-capacitors-use-same-value-or-mult

Answer (score 1):

Using different value capacitors filters different frequencies. So using different values for decoupling generally better. Basicly, bigger capacitors filters low frequencies, smaller capacitors filters high frequencies.
Your values looks OK. I think there is no problem, but to be sure i need to see schematic.