# Lithium Ion Battery : Electrolytic Capacitor At Buck Converter Output

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, electrolytic-capacitor, leakage-current

It is recommended not to parallel electrolytic capacitors with a battery due to the leakage current of the electrolytic capacitor (which is small but worthy of consideration over large time periods) consistently draining the battery — including while the device is not in use.

This clearly applies to anything directly tied to the battery, such as the input capacitor(s) of a voltage converter (such as a buck converter). What about past the voltage converter input — at the output of the voltage converter?

Does electrolytic capacitance leakage current at the output of a parallel voltage converter or past it affect the battery when the converter is not active?

In the case of an IC with an enable switch, if the enable pin was set to disable, would this prevent leakage current from being drawn from the input side of the converter to the output side?

Comment: The enable pin being deactivated won't stop leakage through the device and to any load. My advice is don't use electrolytics if you can avoid them.